# Function Ran in Puppeteer Evaluate Not Behaving the Same as in the Dev Console

Tags: node.js, automation, puppeteer, recaptcha

I am trying to solve a captcha on a page using Puppeteer. I have the captcha answer being properly solved and I am triggering the [data-callback](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param) function for the captcha. In this case, it's `handleCaptcha('ANSWER')`. If I run this function in the developer console, it accepts the answer and moves to the next page. If I run it using `` page[0].evaluate(`handleCaptcha("${answer}")`); `` in puppeteer, it just refreshes the page.

Here is the code:

```
twoClient = new Client(global.twocaptchakey, {
                timeout: 300000,
                polling: 5000,
                throwErrors: true
            });

            // This function takes between 10-300 seconds
            const response = await twoClient.decodeRecaptchaV2({
                googlekey: global.sitekey,
                pageurl: page[0].url()
            });

            const answer = response._text;

            console.log("Captcha Answer:");
            console.log(answer);
            //Here is the problem code
            page[0].evaluate(`handleCaptcha("${answer}")`);
            // page[0].evaluate(answer => {
            //     handleCaptcha(answer);
            // }, answer)
            
            //Make sure that no code running later interferes with this
            await page[0].waitFor(10000);
```

This uses [Infosimple's Node TwoCaptcha wrapper](https://github.com/infosimples/node_two_captcha)

I've tried both variations of `evaluate()` as shown above, single and double quotes, etc. The `evaluate()` function works fine (tested on alerts). When I run `handleCaptcha('ANSWER');`, in the console, I use the answer logged above, so I know that the two functions are running the same thing.

[Here](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/162) is the same bug popping up in a library. I noticed that in both cases, this is happening on a PerimeterX page. Is it possible for them to modify the behavior of Puppeteer?

In case you want it, [here](https://pastebin.com/yg1sk5sM) is the full code (mostly from ramsessalcedo/chegg-bot).

Comment: If it's an issue with that lib you should post it in their issue tracker rather than ask about it here.

Comment: It's already in an issue tracker. What's unique about this is that PerimeterX seems to have some sort of defense mechanism for preventing console commands from being run through something like Puppeteer. I don't think it's a bug in Puppeteer. I just don't know how it's being done.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?